# Reg exp: extract FIRST number from text

Tags: regex, testing, automation, text-parsing

I just can't figure out how to extract first number from a Textview.

My Textview is

```
"Maximum week limit of this debit card is 300 000 CZK. Limit can be still increased up to 265 944 CZK".
```

What I need is to extract 300 000 number from this object.

I can find the ID of this Textview easily and work with it. Can please someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: you can use regex. to find a number here is link  : https://devqa.io/extract-numbers-string-java-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex approach:

```java
String input = "Maximum week limit of this debit card is 300 000 CZK. Limit can be still increased up to 265 944 CZK";
String firstNum = input.replaceAll("^.*?(\\d[0-9 ]*).*$", "$1");
System.out.println("First number is: " + firstNum);
```

This prints:

```
First number is: 300 000
```

The strategy here is to use regex to capture the first number.  Here is the logic:

```
^                 from the start of the string
    .*?           match all content up to, but not including, the first digit
    (\\d[0-9 ]*)  then match and capture any number of digits or space separators
    .*            match the rest of the input
$                 end of the input
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, here's my code:

`String str = limit.getText(); //gets the string
        str.replaceAll("^.*?(\\d[0-9 ]*).*$", "$1"); //keeps only the first number
        limitsPOSValue.clear();//clears the object i want to put the value in
        limitsPOSValue.sendKeys(str);//sends the first number to the object`

ERROR just says I can't put the whole sentence in there, so it just did not keep only the first number

Comment: Then edit your question and include edge cases for which my answer fails.

Answer (score 0):

Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
Here you can test your regular expressions https://regexr.com/

```
    final String REGX1 = "([0-9]+ [0-9]+)";
    final String REGX2 = "([0-9]+)";
    String sample = "Maximum week limit of this debit card is 300 000 CZK. Limit can be still increased up to 265 944 CZK";
    
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(REGX1);
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(REGX2);
    
    Matcher pm1 = pattern1.matcher(sample);
    Matcher pm2 = pattern2.matcher(sample);
    
    System.out.println("1. REGX");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    int index = 1;
    while(pm1.find())
    {
        System.out.println(index+". "+pm1.group(0));
        index++;
    }
    
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("2. REGX");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    
    index = 1;
    while(pm2.find())
    {
        System.out.println(index+". "+pm2.group(0));
        index++;
    }
```

**`Output`**

```
1. REGX
--------------------------------
1. 300 000
2. 265 944
--------------------------------
2. REGX
--------------------------------
1. 300
2. 000
3. 265
4. 944
```